# Como tornar um ListView responsivo?

Tags: android

Queria que os itens do `ListView` aparecesse com um tamanho responsivo em diferentes resolução de tela, como faço?
Porque eu defini um tamanho das imagens e texto, que fica grande em aparelhos pequenos

Itens do listview:

```
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Como faço para abrir normal em diferentes tamanhos de telas?

Comment: Para deixar responsivo pode usar o [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

Comment: Está faltando código?

Comment: A regra básica é envolver cada LinearLayout num FrameLayout.

Comment: o match_parenrt faz isso,  se alinha conforme sua tela, coloque seu layout completo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dimens` para definir o tamanho dos itens para cada tela.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="indeterminate_progress_size">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Link de referência: [Android Developers - dimen.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html)